# Recording "Access Logs" from JMS via Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

I've got a project that uses Spring Integration to read messages off of a JMS Queue, process them and call a third party system with the results. If it fails, it then rolls the messages back on to the JMS Queue to be retried later.

This all works great. What I want to do now is to record something akin to access logs so that our monitoring tools can monitor throughput in a consistent manner to everything else.

I *think* what I want to do is have some code that wraps the entire JMS Transaction, allowing me to record a Start time, a Stop Time and whether the Transaction was a success or a failure. I can then write my access log messages based on that information and we can get it into our monitoring tools.

So - how do I do that? :)

My Spring Integration Channel Adapter looks like this:

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                         destination="syncQueue"
                         acknowledge="transacted"
                         channel="syncInputChannel"
                         concurrent-consumers="${jms.concurrentConsumers}" />
```

And my Connection Factory like this:

```
<bean id="IBMMQConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="queueManager" value="${jms.queueManager}"/>
    <property name="hostName" value="${jms.hostName}"/>
    <property name="channel" value="${jms.channel}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${jms.port}"/>
    <property name="transportType" value="1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="syncQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="baseQueueName" value="${jms.queueName}" />
</bean>
```

I can't see anything obvious I can attach to either the Connection Factory nor the Channel Adapter that will let me do what I want.

I did try a `ChannelInterceptor`, but this doesn't quite work. I get called on Start and on Success, but not on Failure.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> I did try a ChannelInterceptor, but this doesn't quite work.

What version of Spring Integration are you using? Since 4.0.x, the `ChannelInterceptor` has additional methods, including

```
void afterSendCompletion(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, boolean sent, @Nullable Exception ex);
```

If the exception is not null, it means the transaction will be rolled back.

You could also apply an AOP advice the the channel's `send()` methods.

Comment: As it happens, we're using 3.2.x. I'm trying to upgrade to the latest now, but it's proving a bit painful. Hopefully when I get that done, this will become easy then :)

Comment: Bear in mind, though, that the intercepter is called within the transaction so it won't properly record a condition where the flow succeeds but the transaction commit fails (e.g. because the broker went away). Perhaps a small possibility but I felt I should point it out. As @Artem said in his answer there is really no complete solution with the standard listener container.

Comment: I've got this working now, and it does the job well enough. If the JMS Transaction completely fails - e.g. the broker went away - we've got bigger problems anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The transaction comes from the `MessageListenerContainer` and your `ChannelInterceptor` is called *within*. However if your downstream code throws an exception, the `ChannelInterceptor` still may help. The logic around it is covered in the `AbstractMessageChannel`:

```
public boolean send(Message<?> message, long timeout) {
       ...
        if (interceptors.getSize() > 0) {
            interceptorStack = new ArrayDeque<ChannelInterceptor>();
            message = interceptors.preSend(message, this, interceptorStack);
            if (message == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
      ...
        sent = this.doSend(message, timeout);
      ...
        if (interceptorStack != null) {
            interceptors.postSend(message, this, sent);
            interceptors.afterSendCompletion(message, this, sent, null, interceptorStack);
        }
        return sent;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      ...
        if (interceptorStack != null) {
            interceptors.afterSendCompletion(message, this, sent, e, interceptorStack);
        }
        if (e instanceof MessagingException) {
            throw (MessagingException) e;
        }
        throw new MessageDeliveryException(message,
                "failed to send Message to channel '" + this.getComponentName() + "'", e);
    }
}
```

As you see the `interceptors.afterSendCompletion()` is called from the `catch (Exception e)` block as well. That's how you can get access to the rollback situation as well.

Unfortunately, there is no `adviceChain` option on the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` like we have with the Spring AMQP one, so I can't suggest here you an alternative solution with the `Advice` around TX.